# Optimizing MongoDB driver performance in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, mongodb

```
    client = Mongo::Client.new(hosts.split(","), 
    :database => "#{database}", 
    :replica_set => "#{replica_set}",
    :connection_timeout => 1,
    :socket_timeout => 1,
    :wait_queue_timeout => 1,
    :connect => :replica_set,
    :read => { :mode => :primary_preferred },
    :heartbeat_frequency => 1,
    :min_pool_size => 3,
    :max_pool_size => 20
)
```

I use the code above to connect to a MongoDB database configured as a replica set of three different nodes. Queries are made on an indexed field. I noticed that when the `:connect` option is set to `:direct`, the performance is better as there are no auto-discoveries. But when set to `:replica_set` the performance deteriorates to as much as >12,000 ms. There is actually a node that is not available. Is there any way to improve my configuration as written above to achieve a better performance using the `:connect => :replica_set` option as opposed to `:connect => :direct` option. Any other performance improvement tips will be appreciated. Additionally , I must add that each document queried is large averaging at **15707.931229566184** as given by the `db.stats()` command below

```
uat-replSet:PRIMARY> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "fuse_transactions",
        "collections" : 5,
        "objects" : 1896978,
        **"avgObjSize" : 15707.931229566184**,
        "dataSize" : 29797599968,
        "storageSize" : 44447108352,
        "numExtents" : 114,
        "indexes" : 9,
        "indexSize" : 242091360,
        "fileSize" : 46082293760,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
        },
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 22
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: What kind of queries? `find`s, `update`s or `insert`s?

Comment: Just `find`. An example will be something like `db.collection_name.find({"id":"1234"})` When such is executed, statements like adding node to cluster takes time. But when the setting is changed to `:connect => :direct`, the adding to cluster does not discover all others. Can you kindly explain what `:direct` option does as it might suit my purpose also? I need a recovery plan in place if a node goes down, without impacting performance. How to set up this configuration is what I do not know. Any help will be appreciated